# Viewmodel is created twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I pass an instance of LoginViewModel to my view (Login)
When I click the submit button on the form another instance of LoginViewModel is created.
I can observe this because I put a breakpoint in the constructor.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
@using ViewModels

@model LoginViewModel


<form action="~/Home/VerifyLogin" method="post">  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name:
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUserID, Model.UserList);
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SelectedPassword);
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value ="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
    {
        return View("Login", new LoginViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void VerifyLogin(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        bool sucess = false;

        // some logic

        if(sucess)
            RedirectToAction("ProjectList", "Project");


}
```

ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel :BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList { get; private set; }

    public int SelectedUserID { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPassword { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        Users = DataService.GetUsers();
        UserList = new SelectList(Users, "ID", "Name"); 
    }

    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is created here...

```
return View("Login", new LoginViewModel());
```

And one is created here

```
public void VerifyLogin(LoginViewModel vm)
```

The model binder creates objects and fills them with the parameters it receives from the request. This is normal operation.

To fix your problem, I would do this...

```
public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
{
    var vm = new LoginViewModel()
    {
        Users = DataService.GetUsers();
        UserList = new SelectList(Users, "ID", "Name"); 
    };

    return View("Login", vm);
}

public LoginViewModel()
{
    //Removed code
}
```